# How to get input from a user in Python 3 without being cut off when printing?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, python-3.x

I am making a basic utility in **Python 3** running on **Windows** with which the user inputs commands and at any given time may receive a printed message. The issue is, when using the `input()` function if a user is typing in a command and half way through something is printed out into the console, the result may look like this:

```
this-is-a-command[INFO]User Connected.-that-is-being-cut-off
```

In this scenario, the return of the `input()` command would still be `this-is-a-command-that-is-being-cut-off` although, this does not look very appealing to the user and may cause confusion. I have tried using various tools such as `sys.stdin` with only the same results. If anybody knows a solution to this problem, *hopefully not using 3rd party modules*, that would be great.

Comment: How do you receive and print the message? In a separate thread?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Yes, I am using multiple threads, I realize threading can cause many problems like this, but that is the only way my program will work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single thread for input and output. Have the threads receiving messages put them into a [queue](http://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or [deque](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Then whenever you are not waiting for user input, you can check the queue for messages and output them. For checking for user input without blocking, there is the [msvcrt module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) from the standard library.

Or you use curses http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/, there are inofficial builds for python up until 3.2 (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) and build a more advanced interface on top of it.

That being said, I would not choose the windows command line to build something like that.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are implying, but I would like output to always be able to appear and not have to wait for the user hit enter.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your problem fully. Can you update the question and describe in more detail, what your expected outcome is?

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can explain. To be more specific, I'm making a server that is constantly running, and may be printing out information in a different thread as the user is typing in a command.

Comment: So where would you like the messages to go if not to the terminal? Also, windows `cmd`, powershell, somthing else?

Comment: I would like the text outputted by the console and the text typed in by the user to appear in the same terminal/cmd window. Just without obstructing each other (output text printed before the text being currently being typed by the user).

Comment: I don't have experience with advanced windows command line handling. I've updated my answer with what I know, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I completely agree with you that the Windows command-line is not a very versatile tool, but for Windows, that is my only option. I would like a cross-platform method, although by combining the `curses` and `msvcrt` modules I think I may be able to make it work. Thanks for all your help.